# Two function A and B and I need to know P(B) lower limit and upper limit

Tags: probability

I know that $P(A) = 0.446$ and $P(B\mid A) = 0.468$

How can I calculate $P(B)$ lower limit and upper limit?

I know how to calculate intersection of $A$ and $B$ and it is $0.2087$ and when I know this I can calculate $P(B)$ and I get $0.4679$...

So what are the lower limit and upper limit and how can I calculate those?

Am I doing something wrong or what?

I tried to enter lower limit $0.532$ and for upper $0.468$ but these aren't the right ones.

Should I use lim to solve this?

Comment: Once you know $P(A)$ and $P(A \cap B)$, how did you estimate $P(B)$? i.e. How did you get the value $0.4679$ (which is also for some reason very close to $P(B | A)$). I want to tell you that $P(B)$ cannot be found by using only these two values : you can only get an upper and lower bound for $P(B)$, which one gets by using the inequality Fawad mentions (actually, the former is an equality).

Comment: I calculated it with dividing intersection with P(A) as been teached but that's not right? I am not familiar with inequality Fawad mentios so what is the formula i can use to find these out?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $P(A)=a$ and $P(A\cap B)=b$. Then $b \leq P(B)$ You can construct an example where $B \subset A$ and $P(B)=b$. So the smallest value of $P(B)$is $b$. In this example, $a=0.446$ and $b=(0.446)(0.468)$.

Now $P(A\cap B^{c})=P(A)-P(A\cap B)=a-b$. By above argument the minimum value of $1-P(B)=P(B^{c})$ is $a-b$. This implies that the maximum value of $P(B)$ is $1-(a-b)$